# Making SObject as Serializable

Tags: soap-api

I am executing SOQL queries using SOAP API.It might result in Account or Opportunity or other salesforce data.

I want to use the result i.e SObject to be passed to a another API.

But the target API accepts only Serializable objects

So how can I make SObject as serializable?

Is there a way to generate SObject class itself as a serializable?

Comment: Is your target API a local (non web-service) API? What language are you working in?

Comment: target API is on web-service. I am working in JAVA

Comment: OK, in Java there is more than one SOAP framework. If you are using JAXB see [How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-us); Google for the framework you are using. Or you can manually create serializable classes and transfer the data into those before sending. Or avoid the pain of SOAP altogether and use the JSON/REST Salesforce APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Apex has a native JSON support. You can use the serializeand deserialize methods to serialize the objects. Here is a example.

```
Contact con = [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1]; 
// Set additional field
con.FirstName = 'Joe'; 
String jsonstring = Json.serialize(con); 
System.debug(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Is it possible to Apex in SOAP API?

Comment: Yes it is also possible in Apex and expose in Soap UI. Please refer to this link for reference. http://www.salesforce2u.blogspot.in/2014/12/xml-serialization-in-salesforce-in.html